# encode a file from ASCII to UTF8

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii

I want to encode a csv file from ASCII to UTF-8 encoding and this is the code I tried :

```
import codecs
import chardet
BLOCKSIZE = 9048576 # or some other, desired size in bytes

with codecs.open("MFile2016-05-22.csv", "r", "ascii") as sourceFile:
    with codecs.open("tmp.csv", "w", "utf-8") as targetFile:
        while True:
            contents = sourceFile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            if not contents:
                break
            targetFile.write(contents)


file = open("tmp.csv", "r")
try:
    content = file.read()
finally:
    file.close()
        encoding = chardet.detect(content)['encoding']
print encoding
```

After testing it, I still get "ascii" in the value of encoding. The encoding didn't change. What am I missing?

Comment: Any ASCII file is already a valid UTF-8 file. In fact, it's valid in almost all encodings (which are ASCII based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASCII is a *subset* of UTF-8. Any ASCII-encoded file is also valid UTF-8.

From the [Wikipedia article on UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8):

> The first 128 characters of Unicode, which correspond one-to-one with ASCII, are encoded using a single octet with the same binary value as ASCII, so that valid ASCII text is valid UTF-8-encoded Unicode as well.

In other words, your operation is a no-op, nothing **should** change.

Any tools that detect codecs (like `chardet`) would rightly mark it as ASCII still. Marking it as UTF-8 would also be valid, but so would marking it as ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) or CP-1252 (the Windows latin-1 based codepage), or any number of codecs that are supersets of ASCII. That would be confusing, however, since your data only consists of ASCII codepoints. Tools that would accept ASCII *only* would accept your CSV file, while they would not accept UTF-8 data that consists of more than just ASCII codepoints.

If the goal is to validate that *any* piece of text is valid UTF-8 by using `chardet`, then you'll have to accept ASCII too:

```
def is_utf8(content):
    encoding = chardet.detect(content)['encoding']
    return encoding in {'utf-8', 'ascii'}
```

Comment: is it possible to show in the test result utf-8 instead of ASCII ?

Comment: @Cloudgls: what test result? You didn't  show us at all what you are using to test. And note that 'Latin-1' would also be valid, as CP-1252. ASCII is used as the basis of many encodings. Text that only uses ASCII codepoints is best marked as ASCII, and not as one of the many supersets.

Comment: the result of `print encoding`

Comment: @Cloudgls: Why would you need that? Chardet correctly determined it only sees ASCII characters. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: I need to make a unittest for the encoding function, and I want to check the encoding before and after calling the function on a specific file to decide if the unittest is successful

Comment: @Cloudgls: then don't use ASCII for your test. Use text that uses codepoints outside of that range. Pick Latin-1 for example; use `å` or `ë` or any other valid Latin-1 character, recode *that* and then test. ASCII is the wrong codec for this.

Comment: I can't change the file content. Is there any way to check if the file is UTF8 or not ?

Comment: @Cloudgls: yes, test the codec. If it is detected as either ASCII or UTF-8 it is all valid UTF-8.

Comment: @Cloudgls: This is the point where you as a programmer need to insert code. Chardet is *correct* in marking it as ASCII. But if you need to verify something is valid UTF-8, then ASCII is a valid answer too because ASCII is a subset of UTF-8.

Comment: @Cloudgls If you need to check if a file is UTF-8 or not, you have a failed communication. Sending a text file means either sending both the bytes and the encoding or sending the bytes and agreeing on the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII is a subset of UTF-8; all ASCII files are automatically also UTF-8. You don't need to do anything.